# How do I download files in Python from an website?

Tags: python, download

I need to download all english subtitels from https://www.opensubtitles.org/de. Filelink must be something like this: (https://www.opensubtitles.org/de/subtitleserve/sub/8429220).
This is my code:

```
import requests
import validators
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import wget
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib.request 

def check_validity(my_url):
    try:
        urlopen(my_url)
        print("Valid URL")
    except IOError:
        print ("Invalid URL")
        sys.exit()


def get_srts(my_url):
    links = []
    html = urlopen(my_url).read()
    html_page = bs(html, features="lxml") 
    og_url = html_page.find("meta",  property="og:url")
    base = urlparse(my_url)
    print("base ,base")
    for link in html_page.find_all('a'):
        current_link = link.get('href')
        if current_link.endswith('srt'):
            if og_url:
                print("currentLink",current_link)
                links.append(og_url["content"] + current_link)
            else:
                links.append(base.scheme + "://" + base.netloc + current_link)

    for link in links:
        try: 
            wget.download(link)
        except:
            print(" \n \n Unable to Download A File \n")
    print('\n')


def main():
    #print("Enter Link: ")
    my_url = 'https://www.opensubtitles.org/de/search/sublanguageid-eng/searchonlymovies-on'
    check_validity(my_url)
    get_srts(my_url)

main()
```

The problem is, that my downloader doesn't find any links to download from. og_url is also empty.
Because the filelink is without the ending "srt or zip" i tried to leave out the line (if current_link.endswith('srt'):).
Maybe you have a idea or a tip.

Comment: What does `html_page` look like? Is it the webpage content you were expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Heres an idea or tip:

Well in HTML for a link to download something on click you can add download in the link tag

```
<a href="https://link" download>
```

You could maybe search for those.